# How to connect USB CDC devices?

Tags: raspbian, usb

I have a Zebra MC3300XR SERIES RFID reader that support USB CDC, how can i read the scanned RFID programmatically in the raspberry pi? is it possible?!

Answer (score 1):

Good news, the Raspbian has CDC ACM drivers already built in as plug-and-play, so /dev/ttyACM0 should show up when you plug your adapter in if it actually  CDC ACM.
"/dev/ttyACM0" is USB0, On my system they generally show up as "/dev/ttyUSBx" I have seen on some of my Linux machines but not recently. That also varies with the IDE I am using.

Comment: Maybe expand on what you mean by "/dev/ttyACM0 should show up when you plug your adapter in"?